# Set timeout shell script

Tags: bash, timeout

I want set timeout in my shell script, this is my code:

```
 /etc/init.d/ntp stop
until ping -nq -c3 8.8.8.8; do
   echo "Waiting for network..."
done
ntpdate -s time.nist.gov
/etc/init.d/ntp start
```

I want set time out 30 seconds, if more than 30 seconds I want kill that process and change to this process:

```
hwclock -s
```

Thankyou

Comment: Why is it tagged python?

Answer (score 2):

In bash you can use [timeout](http://linux.die.net/man/1/timeout).

```
timeout 30s script.sh
hwclock -s
```

Comment: thaknyou, but I want timeout in my script. do you have any advise?

Comment: @ImamAbdulMahmudi what's stopping you from using timeout in your script?